# Why doesn't Googles Javascript code for AES Encryption work in this code?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
var toEncMes = "This is a secret message.";
var secPas = "myPassword";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(toEncMes, secPas);

alert (encrypted);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, secPas);
alert (decrypted);
</script>
```

I probably just don't understand the concept but I have no idea.

The end result from my code is still just a jumbled mess when I display decrypted result.

I found this here:
https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

The original entry looks like this:

The Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) is a U.S. Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS). It was selected after a 5-year process where 15 competing designs were evaluated.

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js">    </script>
<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
</script>
```

CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase, then it will generate a 256-bit key.

Comment: AES is symmetric so passing the same passphrase to both should be fine.  `"myPassword"` is too small a secret for any variant of AES, so it's probably creating a secret from that.  Maybe it does that for `encrypt` but not for `decrypt`.  Can you try using a 256 bit key instead of a passphrase?

Comment: I added more details to my post. Anyhow, what it says is: "If you use a passphrase, then it will generate a 256-bit key." So, if I'm reading that correctly, I shouldn't have to use one right?

Comment: It sounds like it's really not as simple as I thought it was based off what I just read here, looks like I have some learning to do:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/crypto-js/AES/crypto-js/p5WZ7U7Iwcg/28maZPVW3FgJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are alerting the raw decrypted object - the default encoding for such is hex. It needs to be converted to a string using the appropriate human-readable encoding:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
var toEncMes = "This is a secret message.";
var secPas = "myPassword";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(toEncMes, secPas);

alert (encrypted);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, secPas);
alert (decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // <---- note specified encoding
</script>
```

Of course, the usual cryptographic warning signs still apply: this doesn't ensure your message has not been tampered with, etc.